# How can I create image tags?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, printing, tiff

I have the following function that allows me to iterate through each page in a multi-page single tiff file.

```
// This function will iterate all pages, one at a time. //

 protected void PrintAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    // counts number of pages in the fax document.//
    int number = _FaxPages.Count;

    // for loop to iterate through each page. //
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        string _FaxId = Page.Request["FaxId"];

        _PageIndex = i;

        imgFax.ImageUrl = "ShowFax.ashx?n=" + _FaxId + "&f=" + _PageIndex + "&mw=750";

        PrintAll.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return printing()");             
    }
}
```

I want to know how to dynamically create separate image tags within the for loop...such that  I can use these images to print all the pages inside the tiff file.

Right now If I use window.print() in my javascript.. it prints the entire webpage along with buttons, links, text boxes, check boxes, etc.. I just need to be able to print only the images inside the fax document which is a SINGLE TIFF FILE with MULTIPLE PAGES (FRAMES).

please help.

Comment: if you have a webpage it would be easier to extract all images from that page, then load a new page with those extracted images on it and on that new page call `window.print()`.

Comment: can you show me some code on how to do that? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a alternate stylesheet that is for printing.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

and in your case you could hide all elements and show only `img` tags. This seems pretty specific so maybe create a `print.fax.css` and use it on this page only.